# How to check if a Windows 8.1 PC ever connected to the Internet?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, connection

Is there a way to determine if Windows 8.1 was ever connected to the Internet by a wired connection? Maybe the event log can tell the story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most wired Ethernet drivers will log an event to the Windows System Event log when a cabled network connection is established.  **However, the event *Source* and *Event ID* vary from one driver to the other.**

On my Windows computer, when a wired connection is established, event ID 15 with the source iANSMini port is logged:

```
Adapter link up: Intel(R) 82567LM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
```

The best thing to do is review the System Event log for a similar event.

To determine if the computer was actually *connected to the Internet* is another story.  You can review the *NetworkProfile* event log (in Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > NetworkProfile > Operational) to see what network profiles(s) the computer has accessed.  An example event:

```
Network Connected
    Name: internal.local
    Desc: internal.local
    Type: Managed
    State: Connected,IPV4 (Local)
    Category: Private
```

If you know that network has Internet access, then you would know the computer had the *potential* for Internet access.

Comment: maybe try CTRL+F "link up" in the log